# cross compile: check if it is possible to build 32 bit on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, waf

While building a C++ project, we have serveral targets:
32 and 64 bits.

On some 64 bit machines, while building 32 bit target we are getting a failures because g++-multilib is missing:

```
/usr/include/features.h:374:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
```

**My question is this:**

What is the best way to query if the current machine is able to generate a 32 bit image, in terms of compiler and glibc packages installed.

One solution could be, for example,
generating a simple C file that contains multiple glibc includes and see if I am able to compile the mock file.

This does not seem the elegant solution.

Instead, I would like to query the machine to see if all the nesscary packages are installed.

P.S:

We are using WAF as a build infrastructure.

Thanks,

Itay

Comment: Maybe [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/54736/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-installed) will help?

Answer (score 5):

checking for the existence of a given package is usually *not* a good idea, as it relies on specific distributions (e.g. Fedora) and specific package names (e.g. `libc6-dev-i386`); other distributions (or other versions of the same distributions) will have different package names and tools to interact with the package manager (e.g. `apt` vs `rpm` vs ...)

the well-established autotools way is to run tests for the things that you actually need (e.g. include a given header file) rather than check for things that *might* provide the things you need (e.g. a certain package)-

e.g. if your actual code requires to include `features.h`, then you should test (in a pre-build step) whether it is possible to include this file without errors.

the following autotools example will stop with an error if `features.h` cannot be used; which allows the user to fix the problem by installing the correct packages (e.g. as hinted in your README) before starting a time-consuming build process.

```
 #snippet from configure.ac
 #stop configure process if we cannot use foo.h
 AC_CHECK_HEADERS([foo.h],,AC_ERROR([cannot include foo.h - try installing libfoo-dev])
```

if instead of failing the configure step you would rather simply disable parts of your build, you might want to do something like this:

configure.ac:

```
 have_bar_h="no"
 AC_CHECK_HEADERS([bar.h],[have_bar_h="yes"])
 AM_CONDITIONAL([BAR]) [ test "x${have_bar_h}" = "yes" ]
```

and Makefile.am

```
 if BAR
 # only do the 32bit build if we have bar.h
 bin_PROGRAMS+=coolapp32
 ebduf
```

sorry that this answer is very autotools specific, but i'm sure that `waf` has similar ways; check the section about [Configuration helpers](https://waf.io/book/#_configuration_helpers) in the *WAF documentation*.

Comment: Indeed it is fairly easy to have such checks in waf: https://waf.io/book/#_configuration_helpers

Answer (score 0):

It might help,

try to install **libc6-dev-i386** on your machine which is Embedded GNU C Library: 32-bit development libraries for AMD64.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to query the machine to see if all the necessary 32 bit packages are installed...

```
rpm -qa --queryformat 'libc6-dev-%{ARCH}\n' | grep 'i[6543]86' | cut -d' ' -f1
```